# lookahead and group

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

In Java, on a text like `foo <on> bar </on> thing <on> again</on> now`, I should want a regex with groups wich give me with a find "foo", "bar", empty string, then "thing", "again", "now".

If I do `(.*?)<on>(.*?)</on>(?!<on>)`, I get only two group (*foo bar, thing again*, and I've not the end "now").

if I do `(.*?)<on>(.*?)</on>((?!<on>))` I get *foo bar empty string*, then *thing again and empty string* (here I should want "now").

Please what is the magical formula ?

Thanks.

Comment: This looks very much like XML. Is it *actually* XML? If so, use an XML API instead of a regex.

Comment: You have a problem ? You want to solve it using regular expressions ? Well, guess what ?

Comment: Where's the empty string coming from?

Comment: Yes it's xml, but I'm trying with regex :-) I don't understand Riduidel comment, sorry.

Comment: Regex is by definition incapable of reliably working with irregular languages like XML. @Riduidel is referring to an infamous quote by Jamie Zawinsky which you'll sadly find referenced in every other regex question here on SO - but in this case it's appropriate.

Comment: @Tim: I wouldn't say "`Regex` is by definition...". "`Regular languages` by definition..." sure, but there's no one definitive regex. You are right that people abuse regex for things just like this, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendations

- there is no need to match text before `<on>` and after `</on>`
- use non greedy flags to match text between `<on>` and next `</on>`
- use a loop with `Matcher.find()` to sequence through all occurences, if possible. No need to do all at once with one big fat regexp!

Comment: Fine. Your program will be more readable and maintenable that way.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on doing this with regex, then you can try to use `\s*<[^>]*>\s*` as delimiter:

```
    String text = "foo <on> bar </on> thing <on> again</on> now";
    String[] parts = text.split("\\s*<[^>]*>\\s*");
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(parts));
    // "[foo, bar, thing, again, now]"
```

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you need, because it's not exactly clear.

---

Perhaps something like this was required:

```
    String text = "1<on>2</on>3<X>4</X>5<X>6</X>7<on>8</on><X>9</X>10";
    String[] parts = text.split("\\s*</?on>\\s*|<[^>]*>[^>]*>");
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(parts));
    // prints "[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, , 10]"
```

This doesn't handle nested tags. If you have those, you'd really want to dump regex and use an actual HTML parser.

If you don't want the empty string in the middle of the array, then just `(?:delimiter)+`.

```
    String text = "1<on>2</on>3<X>4</X>5<X>6</X>7<on>8</on><X>9</X>10";
    String[] parts = text.split("(?:\\s*</?on>\\s*|<[^>]*>[^>]*>)+");
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(parts));
    // prints "[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10]"
```

Comment: No, sorry, I want to catch <on> and only <on>, but not <in> for instance.

Comment: @Istao: Still not clear. Why do you need `foo` and `thing`, then? Edit question with A LOT MORE examples.